# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Bigl[\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+1^2}\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}\Bigr)...+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr]$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

> Find the limit of $\Bigl[\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+1^2}\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}\Bigr)...+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr]$ using Riemann integrals of a suitable function.

$\Bigl[\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+1^2}\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}\Bigr)...+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr]=\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigl[\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{1+(\dfrac{1}{n})^2}\Bigr)+\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{1+(\dfrac{2}{n})^2}\Bigr)+...\Bigr]$

Hence the function is $\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\Bigr)$ and it goes from $0$ to $1$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\sin\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\Bigr)dx=?$

This is not an easy integral to compute, but the main question in this exercise is i think to convert the sum into an integral and not the computing, So maybe i did a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: your first equation is wrong.

Comment: As noticed mookid your equation is not correct, $\sin \frac{x}{n}\ne \frac{1}{n}\sin x$

Comment: @MherSafaryan at $n \to \infty$ it is. That's not rigoros, but valid.

Comment: @MherSafaryan Yes, that was wrong. but i still couldn't find the correct transformation

Comment: @O.B.D.A. at $n\to\infty$ it is/

Comment: *i think*  so. not sure

Comment: @Sabyasachi, it is true when we take a limit, but it gives us nothing for solving the limit of O.B.D.A

Comment: ah right. I see. I keep making that mistake. :p

Comment: in my mind I just think $\sin(x) = x$ for small x. that's not entirely valid.

Comment: when I say small I mean $x\to 0$ of course.

Comment: wolfram alpha failed. are you sure the question is correct @O.B.D.A.?

Comment: @Sabyasachi. Yes, it was one of these ''warming-up'' exercises, cannot believe that it is so difficult.

Comment: This question has totally stumped me.

Comment: @all, I can't even input the question correctly into wolfram alpha. what do I do to 

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{n}{i^2 + n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Numerical evaluation(brute force) seems to lead to $\pi/4$ Ideas?

Comment: @MherSafaryan any thoughts on $\pi/4$?

Comment: you get the answer if the sum has the $\sin$ yet it magically dissapears from the integral. weird.

Comment: my best guess is that my original thought of $\sin(x) = x$ as $x\to0$ holds. we have to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, as $n \to \infty$, the argument of the sine function is small so that we may make the approximation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin{\left ( \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\right )} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}$$

which is indeed a Riemann sum with limit

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Comment: It doesn't seem to be convincing that approximation. Can you explain more detailly ?

Comment: @Ron Gordon This is the upper bound, maybe we need also a lower bound, by the way the result is correct.

Comment: @MherSafaryan: argument of sine is $$ \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \frac1{n} \frac1{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}} $$ so that $$ \frac1{2 n} \lt \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} \lt \frac1{n}$$ The argument of the sine is thus small so that $\sin{x} \approx x$ in this limit

Comment: I think this answer is convincing because the series is unique convergence so that the 'lim' and sum can be exchanged. Then use the equivalence infinitesimal we can get the answer.

Comment: Taylor Expansion explains the rest of it.

Since $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-...$ then we get;

$x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}<\sin(x)<x$,and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{3!}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\Bigl    (\dfrac{n}{n^2+k^2}\Bigr)^3<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\Bigl     (\dfrac{n}{n^2}\Bigr)^3=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\to0$

Comment: This question is so nice, so basically, in some instances, where $\alpha \approx 0$ (you can also assume that $x \approx 0$), you should use the approximation $\sin (\alpha x) \approx \alpha x$, rather than $\sin (\alpha x) \approx \alpha \sin x$. At first glance, I thought the latter approximation should be 'better', but it turns out, it's not. Interesting.